# Order statistics of a single random variable

Tags: self-study, order-statistics

I have trouble understanding the following question:

> We have **N** i.i.d random variables from the uniform distribution between 0 and 1. If **N=1**, what is the probability that the **n^th** order statistic is less than or equal to the value **x**? (In other words, what is $$Pr(X_1^{(n)} \leq x )$$?)

If N = 1, then we have single r.v.. Can we even speak about n-th smallest value in such cases? Minimum of one uniform r.v. should be simple x. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure you transcribed the question correctly?  At "N=1" there appears to be some kind of typographical error.  Based on what you are asked to show, it looks like "$n=N$" was intended.

Comment: @whuber [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/jwQnhMS.png). It should be a pretty simple question, but the way it worded confuses me.

Comment: What the screenshoot shows is $X_1^{(n)}$ not $X_1^n$, which makes more sense. Please edit! Hint: If $n=1$, which (one) observation is the the minimum? Which distribution does that have?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks. So I need to find probability that minimum of n iid unifrom r.v. is less than x. $ P(X_1^n < x ) = 1 - P[min(X_1, X_2 ... X_n) >x] = 1- (1- F_X(x))^n= 1 - (1 - x)^n$

Answer (score 1):

When you have a sample size of $N=1$, there is no ordering to be done, so the order statistics is just the sample itself. That is
$$ X^{(1)}_1 = X_1$$
So it follows that
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}} 
    \P( X^{(1)}_1 \le x)= \P( X_1 \le x)
$$

Comment: Nice explanation (+1) . Less intuitively, there is a permutation on a single element: the identity function.